# Does Eclipse really need Git to check Java class files?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm working on a Java project using Eclipse as IDE and tortoiseGit as Git client.

I don't really want to commit the bin directory of the Eclipse project (containing *.class files) but I want to ensure that one is able to run a freshly cloned project right from Eclipse. 
If I remove the class files then I do only check what I really want but if I clone this version Eclipse won't be able to run this project. It doesn't find the classes (the class files).

I am quite new to Eclipse so I couldn't figure out how to rebuild the class files from *.java source files. Would that do the trick anyway? Or do I have do something else to achieve what I want (runnable repository, no class files in it)?

Comment: The `.class`-files are the compiled `.java`-files. You don't need those to import an existing project into your Eclipse-Workspace. How did you go about importing the project?

Comment: Oh well, import worked. So my fault was that I wanted to reproduce the situation right after the cloning by deleting the bin folder by myself. Sorry.
(And found Project\Clean... just a minute ago for rebuilding.)

Comment: You'll want to use the "Import"-assistance to import an existing project. All the importer needs are the `.classpath` and `.project`-files.

Comment: If you've figured out your problem then this question should be deleted.  It is most likely going to be little help for others.

Answer (score 1):

If someone should re-build your project, the easiest way would be to hit the "Run" button in Eclipse.

The method above is not sophisticated. You could 8and probalby should) provide an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) [build file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant#Sample_build.xml_file). Ant files are the common way to accomplish what you ask for (though they need some time because of a higher learning curve).

Comment: I actually deleted the bin folder by myself (as stated in the comment to my question). When I "run" the project from with Eclipse afterwards, it wasn't able to find the main class anymore. Using Eclipse's clean command helped me there. But yes, this seems not to be the best method. Maybe I should really look up that Ant build file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check in the `.project` and `.classpath` files and the `.settings`folder into git. Those files tell Eclipse how the project is configured (build classpath, source directories, etc).